# TabPageIndicator setVisibility() doing nothing

Tags: android, android-studio, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to use `TabPageIndicator`  in my app, but it always crashes when I want to run it. After that, I set the `android:visibility="gone"` in the `com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator` and it doesn't crash anymore, but can't make it visible now. I've stepped with the debugger, it reaches the point where it calls `setVisibility()`. Do anyone know how to make `TabPageIndicator`  visible during the execution of the program? The viewpager works well when there is no indicator.

The calling code:

```
private void displayWords() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String word:words)
    {
        fragments.add(WordFragment.newInstance(word));
    }

    wordsAdaptor adapter = new wordsAdaptor(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabPageIndicator tabIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);

    tabIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
    tabIndicator.setVisibility(TabPageIndicator.VISIBLE);


}
```

adapter:

```
public class wordsAdaptor extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public wordsAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"

    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    />

<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/titles"

    custom:color="@android:color/darker_gray"

    android:visibility="gone"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

compile directives:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
```

Internet permissions are defined in manifest.

Comment: Have you tried Invisible instead of gone? If it is gone, the TabPageIndicator is not layouted. Otherwise set the Pager and the Adapter if the TabPageIndicator is visible and ready

Comment: @oberflansch, it causes app to crash with exception `ViewPager is not bounded`. I've set the adapter before setting the pager to indicator as was recommended in another post.